# Pandas get one hot encodings from a column as booleans

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

I'm considering a Pandas Dataframe. I would like to find an efficient way in which the second Dataframe is created.

```py
import pandas as pd
data = {"column":[0,1,2,0,1,2,0]}   
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```py
column
0
1
2
0
1
2
0
```

```py
column0  column1 column2
true      false     false
false      true     false
false      false     true
true      false     false
false      true     false
false      false     true
true      false     false
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a `get_dummies` problem, but you will additionally need to specify `dtype=bool` to get columns of bools:

```
pd.get_dummies(df['column'], dtype=bool)                                                                                                  
       0      1      2
0   True  False  False
1  False   True  False
2  False  False   True
3   True  False  False
4  False   True  False
5  False  False   True
6   True  False  False

pd.get_dummies(df['column'], dtype=bool).dtypes                                                                                          
0    bool
1    bool
2    bool
dtype: object
```

---

```
# carbon copy of expected output
dummies = pd.get_dummies(df['column'], dtype=bool)
dummies[:] = np.where(pd.get_dummies(df['column'], dtype=bool), 'true', 'false')  

dummies.add_prefix('column')
  column0 column1 column2
0    true   false   false
1   false    true   false
2   false   false    true
3    true   false   false
4   false    true   false
5   false   false    true
6    true   false   false
```

Comment: nice one on `dtype = bool`. +1

Comment: @AndyL. Thanks. I didn't know it existed until I tried it off chance and it actually worked (:

Comment: **HAX**: `pd.get_dummies(df.column).applymap(['false', 'true'].__getitem__).add_prefix('column')`

Comment: @piRSquared very piR-esque, as usual :D

Answer (score 2):

I also use `get_dummies` as cs95. However, I use `str.get_dummies` and concat the word `column` before `get_dummies`. Finally, `replace`

```
('column'+df.column.astype(str)).str.get_dummies().replace({1:'true', 0:'false'})


Out[2164]:
  column0 column1 column2
0    true   false   false
1   false    true   false
2   false   false    true
3    true   false   false
4   false    true   false
5   false   false    true
6    true   false   false
```

Answer (score 1):

#### `factorize` and slice assignment

```
i, u = pd.factorize(df.column)

a = np.empty((len(i), len(u)), '<U5')
a.fill('false')
a[np.arange(len(i)), i] = 'true'

pd.DataFrame(a).add_prefix('column')

  column0 column1 column2
0    true   false   false
1   false    true   false
2   false   false    true
3    true   false   false
4   false    true   false
5   false   false    true
6    true   false   false
```